# My audio does fetch from the server, but displays 'audio of undefined' when I click on my audio button

Tags: javascript, audio

I have an audio button that should fetch audio from the server and then 'display' it. I did `console.log()` and it does fetch from the server, but it doesn't play when I click on the audio button. it gives me an error in my `console.log()` when I click on the audio button with:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Line 127 is the error given, this is line 127:

```
var foundID = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf($(this).parent().find
('.exerciseWord').html().toLowerCase() + '.mp3')
```

the global variables I use:

```
var MEDIAARRAY;
var WORDS;
var audioArray;
var audio = new Audio();
```

This is the complete code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".sound", function () {
console.log(audioArray);
 var foundID = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf($(this).parent().find('.exerciseWord').html().toLowerCase() + '.mp3')
 var currentVal = $(this).parent().find('.fa-volume-up');
    if (foundID > -1) {
        var audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = 'TheServerWhereTheAudioIsBeingFetchedFrom' + MEDIAARRAY.audio.path + MEDIAARRAY.audio.files[foundID] + '';
        audio.play();
    }
});
```

https://medium.com/@sarahelson81/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-in-javascript-c81e00f4a5e3 I read this article and it basically says: If the script comes accross a variable that isn't defined it will throw the error, but how do I want to define `toLowerCase`? It only changes the letters to lowerCase.So what does does the error refer to? Before the complete code I have this (not sure if this is useful, but maybe it's a key? if not, please edit and take it out, because i'm not sure about it being very useful or not.)

```
function getFileArray(param)
{

var request = {
    language: param
};

$.ajax(
{
    url: "TheUrlThatMakesConection",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: request,
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (response)
{
    console.log(response)
    MEDIAARRAY = response;
    audioArray = response.audio;
    //console.log(audioArray);


});
}
```

Comment: MEDIAARRAY what does the data structure look like. Can you console.log it and put it in your question.

Comment: If MEDIAARRAY is an array, you are using dot notation to access an array, which does not work in JS

Comment: I will console.log it for you, just a sec. well, MEDIAARRAY is just a gloable variable (maybe I should've used a better name for it, agree on that one)

Comment: When you say MEDIAARRAY.audio that is what is coming up as undefined. The toLowerCase function cant execute on an undefined variable

Comment: oh, but I set the MEDIAARRAY variable (global) like this: var MEDIAARRAY; EDIT:  the console.log doesn't show anything in particular. besides showing there are files on the server etc.

Comment: In your done function in your ajax request, you are setting MEDIAARRAY to response. What are You expecting that to be

Comment: a response from the server?

Comment: Yeah. What type of data structure?

Comment: That's a good one, In all honesty: I have no idea about the data structure, it's a server I just ask for a response. it does work in my CMS side however... is there any code ur looking for specific??

Comment: `toLowerCase` is a string method so make sure whatever you call it on is a string